# Properties file on HikariCP

Tags: java, properties, mariadb, hikaricp

I tried unsuccessfully configure hikaricp and I don't see error in the code please help.

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    private DatabaseClient[] databaseClients;
    private HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;

    public DatabaseManager(String absoluteFilePath) {
        final HikariConfig hikariConfig = new  HikariConfig(absoluteFilePath);
        this.hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        System.out.println(hikariConfig.getUsername()); // null u-u
    }
}
```

Properties file:

```
## Database Settings
dataSourceClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource
dataSource.user=root
dataSource.password=
dataSource.databaseName=imagine-db
dataSource.portNumber=3306
dataSource.serverName=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the username on the data source not on the config itself. This will still work fine but you can't access it using `hikariConfig.getUsername()`.

Try adding this to your properties file if you really need to access the user like that, although I suspect you don't.

```
username=root
password=
```